# Stuck in truffle compile

Tags: truffle, ropsten, infura

When I run `truffle compile` it stuck forever after compiling contracts . I am importing openzeppelin library and  using infura , ropsten and metamask to deploy contract on testnet. . Here is the output

```
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/obaidminttoken.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/BasicToken.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Basic.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/MintableToken.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol...
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts
```

Here is my truffle.js file

```
require('dotenv').config();
const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 7545,
      gas: 6500000,
      network_id: "5777"
    },
    ropsten: {
        provider: new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNENOMIC, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/" + process.env.INFURA_API_KEY),
        network_id: 3,
        gas: 4500000
    },
  }
};
```

Comment: `truffle compile` just compiles. If you want to deploy, use `truffle migrate`

Comment: What is your Truffle version?

Comment: @goodvibration Truffle v4.1.8 (core: 4.1.9)
Solidity v0.4.24 (solc-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the filename is the same as the contract's name, eg.
if the contract's name is : **Voting**, name the file `voting.sol`.
If that doesn't work, try deleting json files under `build/contracts/` and run `truffle compile` again.

For more info check out https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-migrate/issues/14

Comment: Yes I have checked . I tried to run this command `truffle migrate --network ropsten` without compiling and it stuck at saving artifacts . One thing I want to ask do I need to change my `1_initial_migration.js` or just `2_initial_migration.js` file ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue fixed by wrapping HDWallet provider in truffle.js file . Here is an updated truffle.js code

```
require('dotenv').config();
const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 7545,
      gas: 6500000,
      network_id: "5777"
    },
    ropsten: {
        provider:function() { return new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNENOMIC, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/" + process.env.INFURA_API_KEY);},
        network_id: 3,
        gas: 4500000
    },
  }
};
```